# How do i get buildnumbers per branch in vsts (now azure devops)

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm creating build definitions in vsts. 
I'm using $(Rev:.r) as my build number format. 
I want to be able to use this scheme separately for each branch. 
For example if i have 3 branches, master/develop/feature 
Master builds start from 1,2,3
Develop builds start from 1,2,3
Feature builds start from 1,2,3

Comment: What did you end up doing?  Build Counters you linked to seems to be kinda what we want as well. But only for feature branch builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that Build number format can be configured at the Build definition level.

You can simply create a separate build definition for each branch.

- Build Definition for master
- Build Definition for develop
- Build definition for feature

With the Build#Format as `$(Rev:.r)`

Comment: i want to use a single build definition. So if i have 3 feature branches lets say f1,f2,f3, then my build numbers could look like 1,2,3 ... for f1, 1,2,3 ... for f2 and 1,2,3 ... for f3. 
This is possible in jenkins with multibranch pipelines.

Comment: @user1339246 you can do the multibranch pipelines using scripting but the build # will not be configured differently in the same build definition. like you mentioned f1,f2,f3 is not possible within the same build definition

Comment: @user1339246 please accept the answer so that it will help others

Comment: i dont have enough reputation to do that.

Comment: @user1339246 I think for accepting there is no need reputation  since you are the author of OP.Please [refer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

So theres an update in a recent release that mitigates this to some degree.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2018/sprint-142-update#add-custom-build-counters-to-your-builds

With this, you can use a build number format like $(Build.SourceBranchName)-$(rev:r)

if you have 3 branches test1,test2,test3, you build nos will be like
test1-1
test1-2
test1-3 and so on 
test2-1
test2-2
test2-3 and so on
test3-1
test3-2
test3-3 and so on